# What type of weapon is the Boombox?

Tags: swag-and-sorcery

In my Swag Shop I have access to buy the Boombox weapon blueprint, but I have no idea what type of weapon this is and which stat it is linked to.

Which character stat determines the damage of the Boombox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to steam user [sylva1983](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198241567332):

> "Weapon: Boombox [+30 group physical armour] (damage based on STA, ranged weapon)"

[Source.](https://steamcommunity.com/app/929010/discussions/0/1651043958642866011/)

Comment: I guess it's a "Special" weapon then, thanks!